# Parse a json file and echo value during a foreach in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am facing a problem since several hours...

I have this type of json:

```
{
    "datas": {
        "General": [
            {
                "field": "hotel_name",
                "maxlength": "15"
            },
            {
                "field": "logo",
                "maxlength": "0"
            }
        ],
        "Rooms": [
            {
                "field": "room_1",
                "maxlength": "15"
            },
            {
                "field": "room_2",
                "maxlength": "15"
            },
            {
                "field": "room_3",
                "maxlength": "15"
            }
        ]        
    }
}
```

I want to loop in this json in order to print:

- General

  - hotel_name
- Rooms

  - room_1
  - room_2
  - room_3

So I tried:

```
<?php
// copy file content into a string var
$json_file = file_get_contents('datas.json');

// convert the string to a json object
$jfo = json_decode($json_file);

// copy the posts array to a php var
$datas = $jfo->datas;

foreach ($datas as $data) {
  echo $data[0];
}
?>
```

But nothing is printed...

Any help please ?

Thanks.

Comment: There are a few issues, but the primary one is that your JSON is invalid (you have trailing commas after all of the `maxlength` declarations).

Comment: [Demonstration of invalid JSON](http://codepad.org/WuITSd24) - [correct version](http://codepad.org/3ECg5cUN). Once you fix the JSON, you will get `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`.

Comment: @SeanBright: sorry copy/paste/rearrange for SO mistake.

Comment: @sjagr, how I could solve it?

Comment: I dunno. You can certainly output all the data with `foreach ($datas as $data) {
  foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo $item->field;
    echo $item->maxlength;
  }
}` but there is no meaningful way to organize it into the format you want. Did you make this JSON?

Comment: @sjagr: yes I made it. What do you propose for the structure ?

Comment: JSON-type storage should be parent/child based. If the `Rooms` belong to the `hotel_name`, then the JSON `Rooms` should be stored as children of `hotel_name`, etc.. Look up "NoSQL".. a quick search [yields this article](http://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/nosql-databases-overview) which seems to explain it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another loop for the second level, and you will need to get the key to display the first level title. Rough html in the example to illustrate desired output:

```
foreach ($datas as $name => $data) {
    echo "<ul><li>$name<ul>";
    foreach($data as $room) {
        echo "<li>{$room->field}</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul></li></ul>";
}
```